# about HP ALM User Interface Resolution

Tags: user-interface, alm, hp-quality-center

I just starting to use the `HP ALM QC` and wonder if you could help me some pointer regarding the problem with User Interface.

Follows the printscreen of HP ALM:

[image]

The Problem is that the words on the User Interface are not properly shown and I already tried with zoom in or out and change the windows screen resolution but there are no change on it.

I already tried, the solution from the HP forum but it give no improvement.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What was the solution from the HP forum?

Comment: I already try that one. it have to change text size value from 0x0008 to 0x000A in register. but it doesnt give any improvement on the QC User Interface....

Comment: Which browser are you using? Usually the default and suggested one to us was IE (Internet Explorer), if you use a different one, that might be the cause.

Comment: Hi I am using internet explorer standard from win 10

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the LargeUI mode when you´re connecting via browser:

```
    [...]/qcbin/start_a.jsp?LargeUI=true
```

Comment: His screenshot looks as if the large UI is already in place, and the issues he has with it are exactly why large UI is a nice try, but not useful enough imho.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

Right-click on the application's shortcut or executable file.
Select "Properties" from the context menu.
In the Properties window, navigate to the "Compatibility" tab.
Under the "Settings" section, check the box for "Override high DPI scaling behavior."
Choose the desired scaling mode from the drop-down menu. You can select from options like "Application," "System," or "System (Enhanced)."
Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes